# Passing hidden text values perl cgi

Tags: perl, post, dynamic, cgi

I am currently working on a project where I have to enter in class into to a database and preform some actions on it. One action is editing class. In my edit page I populate a table with all the classes in a db with a edit button which I pass information about that row to a new .pl file. In this file I am trying to read those hidden values I passed to prepopulate some text boxes with those values for updating. I am not able to pass the hidden content to my new file though.

```
print "<form action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/editing.pl method = 'post' >";
my $classid = $row[0];
my $classname = $row[1];
my $dep = $row[2];
my $classnum = $row[3];
my $grade = $row[4];
my $credit = $row[5];
print "<input type='hidden' name='classid' value='$classid' />" ;
print "<input type='hidden' name='classname' value='$classname' />" ;
print "<input type='hidden' name='dep' value='$dep' />" ;
print "<input type='hidden' name='classnum' value='$classnum' />" ;
print "<input type='hidden' name='grade' value='$grade' />" ;
print "<input type='hidden' name='credit' value='$credit' />" ;
print "<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Edit'>";
print "</form>";
print "</td>";
print "</tr>";
```

This is where I dynamically populate my table with the values and then have a edit button to link to the editing.pl page. There I am trying to get the info by doing this

```
#Get the information the user entered
my $id = param('classid');
my $className = param('classname');
my $department = param('dep');
my $classnum = param('classnum');
my $grade = param('grade');
my $credits = param('credit');

print "$id , $className, $department , $classnum, $grade, $credits";#Get the information the user entered
```

But the only output I get is ", , , , ," so the values aren't being transfered. I am not sure as to what the issue is.

EDIT here is my table output. Ignore the empty rows, I hae a bunch in my db when I was experimenting.
[image]

FIX: Had to set my variables before entering the form.

Comment: Are you sure that the values are available in the form, eg can you see them in the HTML source ?

Comment: Yes using the same way I set each variable to print out my table. In my td I print out $row[i] for the data. It shows in the table.

Comment: @GMB you were right. I had to set the variables before entering the form. Thank you

Comment: Please don't put raw HTML in your code. Take a look at [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for some better suggestions.